# \eqref prints the word Equation. How to remove it?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels

Currently, when I type `\ref{eq:myEquation}` or `\eqref{myEquation}` in my thesis, the output is Equation 1.2 or (Equation 1.2), respectively.

I want the output to be 1.2 or (1.2), respectively.
How to remove the word "Equation"?

Perhaps I should redefine the command `\eqref` by writing something like

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{(\ref{#1})},
```

in the preamble. However, #1 seems to be containing the word 'Equation' and I don't know how to get just the number, part of the argument #1.

Comment: Well, simply use `\ref`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bernard This is not a solution. I modified my question. Thanks!

Comment: The output you say your getting for `\ref` and `\eqref` on your system is utterly non-standard. You *must* be using some code (maybe inside a package you load) that's causing this non-standard behavior. Please do edit your posting to provide a minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with`\end{document}`, that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. Please also state which LaTeX engine you use -- pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, something else?

Comment: @Mico I am using a custom documentclass for thesis writing of my university. It is probably using \documentclass{report}, but I cannot figure this out. Providing a MWE is difficult since I already have code in several different files. I was hoping that there is a quick way to redefine the output of \ref and \eqref, so that the word is not printed.

Comment: It sounds like your custom documentclass might be (a) loading the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and (b) redefining `\ref` and `\eqref` to employ `\cref` in the background. To test this theory, do check if `\labelcref{eq:myEquation}` produces anything useful. If it does not, the only thing I can suggest is that you look into the class file (extension: cls) and find out how it redefines `\ref` and `\eqref`.

Comment: @Mico yes, it turned out I am loading \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\labelcref{eq:myEquation} produces the same as \eqref, i.e., (Equation 1.2)

Comment: I still don't know how to keep cleveref and achieve what I want

Comment: It's hard to help when we can't see the actual code that's doing it. Does `\crefname{equation}{}{}` and/or `\Crefname{equation}{}{}` at the end of the preamble do anything? If not, post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) or at least post a link to this documentclass.

Comment: @sdd - The only possible explanation is that the template you are forced to use redefines not only `\ref` and `\eqref`, but `\labelcref` as well, to act like `\cref`. Do keep searching the template code for these redefinitions. Then, undo one or all of them and save the template file under a new name. E.g., if the template file is called `dubious.cls`, name our modified version `dubious-mod.cls`. Start using it by changing `\documentclass[<options>]{dubious}` to `\documentclass[<options>]{dubious-mod}`.

Comment: thanks, I found it

Comment: @sdd -- Do you want to disclose what you found, so that future readers may be able to decide if problems they are experiencing could be related to the ones in this query? Or should this query be closed as having been "solved in the comments"? Please advise.

Comment: Sure, the .cls file contained $\def\p@equation{Equation ~}$. I just removed the word 'Equation'

Comment: @sdd - `\def\p@equation{Equation ~}` sure is an oddball instruction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the cause of the issue the OP wanted to fix was not disclosed in the query and because the issue was fixed by fixing a not previously revealed code anomaly.